# Jquery: create a javascript method called 'containsBlanks' that returns true if any inputs with class 'required' has an empty string in, false if not

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, boolean-logic

```
  I can't seem to quite figure this one out; not sure if I'm even providing a test
```

condition; Also, "blanks" variable is to hold the value of the elements with the".required"   class during the loop.

```
 function containsBlanks(){
var blanks = new Array();
$required.each(function(){
blanks.($(this).val() == "");
});
  return(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you can do this like:

```
$('input.required').filter(function(){ return !this.value });
```

That will give you all required inputs that have an empty value (if any). Then you can check the `length` property to find out if there are any elements in that collection.

Comment: Does this not only get default attributes and not current status?

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your *Nodes* and check their *value* against `""`..

```
function containsBlanks() {
    var i, req = $('.required');
    for (i = 0; i < req.length; ++i)
        if (req[i].value === '')
            return true;
    return false;
}
```